# Token que no expire en api de facebook

Tags: php, facebook-api

Estoy realizando una sigle page. para lo cual estoy utilizando api graph de facebook para poder obtener los ultimos 3 posts que realice en mi pagina de facebook, he logrado obtener el .json con los post pero resulta ser que tengo que generar un token cada cierto tiempo para que siga teniendo acceso a la información del api, he leido la documentacion y veo que solo se pueden generar tokens de 2 hrs que se usan comunmente para sesiones mediante facebook y tambien existe la posibilidad de generar un token que dura aproximadamente 2 meses,... mi cuestion es si hay alguna forma de generar un token que no expire o de que forma podria renovar el token automaticamente para no estarlo haciendo de manera manual -...

les mando un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Creo que facebook no admite tokens permanentes, solo de larga duración como tu lo dices, la explicación completa esta [aquí](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension).

Conseguí algo interesante que quizás te pueda servir

Habiendo descubierto que es posible generar un token de acceso a páginas de Facebook que no caduque, aquí hay un paso claro, paso a paso para todos aquellos que buscan lo mismo:

1. Asegúrate de que eres el administrador de la página de FB de la que deseas sacar información
2. Crear una aplicación FB (debe ser con la misma cuenta de usuario que es la página admin)
3. Vete al Explorador de la Graph API de FB
4. En la parte superior derecha, selecciona la aplicación FB que creaste en la lista desplegable "Aplicación"
5. Haga clic en "Obtener token de acceso"
6. Asegúrese de agregar el permiso manage_pages
7. Convierta este token de acceso de corta duración en uno de larga duración con la llamada a la GraphAPI `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<your FB App ID >&client_secret=<your FB App secret>&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=<your short-lived access token>`
8. Coge el nuevo token de acceso de larga duración devuelto
9. Realiza una llamada de GraphAPI para ver sus cuentas con el nuevo token de acceso de larga duración `https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=<tu token de acceso de larga duración>`
10. Coge el access_token de la página que estarás tirando información
11. Lint el token para ver que está configurado para caducar: nunca!

Deberias hacer eso. ¡Con eso deberias de tener un token a páginas de Facebook que no caduque!

O si usas la SDK de PHP puedes intentar con

```
// Set Extended Access Token
$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();

// Get access short live access token
$accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();

// Exchange token
$facebook->api('/oauth/access_token', 'POST',
    array(  
        'grant_type' => 'fb_exchange_token',           
        'client_id' => 'APP ID',
        'client_secret' => 'APP Secret',
        'fb_exchange_token' => $accessToken
    )
);
```

Para mas información mira la fuente amigo, espero te ayude!

[FUENTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426018/generate-never-expire-access-token-for-facebook-page)